# Boot path not found, cannot start OS

Tags: boot, bootloader, boot-repair

My desktop is 12.04 64bit, and it cannot boot from the hard drive anymore. When I attempt to it just is stuck on a blank screen with an blinking dash, and nothing happens.

I checked with the bios trouble shoot for problems and it said that no boot path could be found. I do not know why this is happening, but need to fix it because it used to boot up normally. What I need to know is how to fix it.

I can boot into a live DVD. Also, there were a few boots I would attempt to boot into a live USB, then it would boot to the hard drive, but that does not work any more.
So with the live DVD (it is an 10.04 LTS 32bit), is there any means to correct the boot path from the live DVD?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can access your files from the live DVD : go to the disk and open the "home" folder. In it are all the users' files.

Were you doing anything such as installing something or uninstalling something when you hit the switch? That could be the cause.

You cannot repair from the live CD with a clear function, but I'm sure this "boot path" it's looking for is something to change in the BIOS, given the fact that the BIOS is the one looking for the boot path. I had this error once and my only solution was reinstalling Ubuntu after backing up my files...

EDIT : If you upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or 12.10 you can choose "upgrade but keep my files". Ubuntu will be reinstalled and upgraded and will try to save a maximum of your files. You should still back them up.

That's all I can do for you... mjchopperboy

Comment: I know I can access my files, from a live DVD/USB. What I need to know is from there can I change grub or whatever file so that the correct boot path is used.